How do I execute code only in one column?
I have a workbook with a double-click function that works when you double click anywhere in the workbook. I need it to be limited to column I. Can I add an if statement or some other check to only populate in I:I?
This is the code right now. I only want it to execute if the double-click is in column I.
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Cancel = True
    
    'copy trace number from trace sheet to main sheet to active cell
        Sheets("trace").Range("F15").copy
        Sheets("Main").Activate
        ActiveCell.Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        'ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select

End Sub


The Target parameter tells you where the click occurred.

If Intersect(Target, Me.Columns("I")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub.

@rotabor i believe you left out the not, or = should be <>.

If Target.Column <> 9 Then Exit Sub

FYI you don't need Activate or ActiveCell/Selection here, or to use Copy/Paste:
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Column <> 9 Then Exit Sub 'from rotabor's comment
    Cancel = True
    Target.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("trace").Range("F15").Value
    Target.offset(1).Select
End Sub

In the event handler, Target represents the double-clicked cell, so you can use that directly.

A Worksheet BeforeDoubleClick: Replace With a Value

The replacement value in Trace!F15 is "Test".
The pink cell is a reminder of the behavior of the UsedRange property which yields in the range A1:K8.
The Find method will search only in this range and find J6 as the bottom-most non-empty cell (yellow).
Therefore the target range is the range I2:I6 representing the only cells that will trigger the event (green).


Sheet Module, e.g. Main
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    InsertTraceValueOnBeforeDoubleClick Target, Cancel
End Sub

Standard Module, e.g. Module1 or modEvents
Sub InsertTraceValueOnBeforeDoubleClick( _
        ByVal Target As Range, _
        ByRef Cancel As Boolean, _
        Optional ByVal DisableEvents As Boolean = False)
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SOURCE_SHEET_NAME As String = "Trace"
    Const SOURCE_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "F15"
    Const TARGET_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "I2"
    Const TARGET_ROW_OFFSET As Long = 1
    Const TARGET_COLUMN_OFFSET As Long = 0
    
    ' How to reference a worksheet ('tws') using one of its ranges ('Target')?
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = Target.Worksheet
    ' In this and the calling event procedure,
    ' 'Target' represents the double-clicked cell.
    
    ' Reference the target last (bottom-most) non-empty cell ('tlcell').
    Dim tlcell As Range:
    Set tlcell = tws.UsedRange.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If tlcell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' empty sheet
    
    ' Reference the target range ('trg').
    
    Dim trg As Range, tRowsCount As Long
    
    With tws.Range(TARGET_FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS)
        tRowsCount = tlcell.Row - .Row + 1
        If tRowsCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' the last row is above the first row
        Set trg = .Resize(tRowsCount)
    End With
    
    ' Check if the target cell is not in the target range ('trg').
    If Intersect(trg, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    ' In this and the calling event procedure, 'Target' is always a single cell.
    ' Therefore you don't need another variable for this cell.
    
    ' Reference the source cell ('scell').
    
    ' How to reference a workbook ('wb') using one of its (work)sheets ('tws')?
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = tws.Parent
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SOURCE_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim scell As Range: Set scell = sws.Range(SOURCE_CELL_ADDRESS)
    
    ' Write the source value to the target cell.
    
    ' Optionally, disable events to prevent triggering a potentially
    ' existing 'Worksheet Change' event.
    If DisableEvents Then Application.EnableEvents = False
        ' Write.
        Target.Value = scell.Value
    
    If DisableEvents Then Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    ' Prevent entering 'Edit' mode.
    Cancel = True
    ' The 'ByRef' in this sub's signature explicitly indicates
    ' that this value is changed in the calling (event) procedure.
    
    ' Select the required cell (adjacent to the bottom of the target cell).
    Application.Goto Target.Offset(TARGET_ROW_OFFSET, TARGET_COLUMN_OFFSET)
    
End Sub

